# Extract data using grep/sed from html tag with special class/id

Tags: sed, grep

I need to grep info from website and it is stored like:

```
<div class="name">Mark</div>
<div class="surname">John</div>
<div class="phone">8434</div>
```

and etc.

Tried to grep it and parse it later with sed:

```
grep -o '<div class="name">.*</div>' | sed -e 's?<div class="name">?|?g'
```

but, when I try to replace with `sed -e 's?<\/div><div class="phone">?|?g'` - no result

and for every class do the same thing. I cannot delete all html tags (`sed 's/<[^>]\+>//g'`), and need to do it only for div with this classes.

The output format should be like

```
|Mark|John|8434|
```

I need to do it with grep/sed

Comment: [Don't.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261561/please-stop-linking-to-the-zalgo-anti-cthulhu-regex-rant/261562)

Comment: I know, that it can be parsed using beatifullsoup in python or selenium or dozens of ways, but I'm asked to do it this way)

Comment: The slash is simply a literal character to `grep`.  You seem to be looking for
`grep -o '<div class="\(name\|surname\|phone\)">.*</div>'`though I guess it could also be [refactored into your `sed` script](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep).

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` should do the job:

```
awk -F"[<>]" '{printf "%s|",$3}' file
Mark|John|8434|
```

If you need a new line at the end:

```
awk -F"[<>]" '{printf "%s|",$3} END {print ""}' file
```

It creates filed separated by `<` or `>` then print the third field with `|` as separator.

Comment: This presumes that the OP has just a single record in the HTML, but my understanding is that they are scraping a page which has multiple such sections. It should not be too hard to refactor the Awk to extract only matching lines and collect the three fields into a single record for each match.

Comment: @tripleee That would be up to OP to answer.  She could do like this to make sure only `div class` lines would be printed:  `awk -F"[<>]" '/<div class/ {printf "%s|",$3}' file`

Comment: Yes, I need to scrap big amount of data and this fields are only part of it. Grep is bigger, and at the end I'm awking fields to load it to database. Awking anything before last awk ruines my script.

Comment: @Jane If you post more of the code and commands you do use, we could possible join the.  There are seldom need for more than one `awk` or mix of `awk`,`grep`,`sed` etc

Comment: Sure, same as the title I need to parse it using grep or sed or mix of them